# How to change selected row's border color and background color of style enabled DBGrid in delphi xe2?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tdbgrid

I used default style "Amethyst Kamri" in application. And my DBgrid's selected row color change according to style. But i want to change selected row's border color and background color.
I change font style using the [answer of following question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9472000)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9472000

Now i want to change color. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need first to inherit the TDBGrid from the Vcl.DBGrids.TDBGrid calss .And override the Paint procedure .
Like this :

```
type
  TDBGrid = class(Vcl.DBGrids.TDBGrid)
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  end;
```

On the Paint procedure :

```
procedure TDBGrid.Paint;
var
  i, X, Y: Integer;
begin
  inherited;
  Y := RowHeights[0] + 1;
  X := Width;
  for i := 1 to Self.RowCount - 1 do
  begin
    Y := Y + RowHeights[i] + 1;
    Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
    Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, Y, X, Y + 1));
  end;
end;
```

And this is the final result :

[image]

Comment: i need to change **slected Row**'s BackGround color also.